# How do I call pod2usage using my caller's documentation?

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments

I'd like to be able to call pod2usage in a method that encapsulates a lot of standardized command line argument handling, but I can't see how I'd be able to put that handling into a separate module and have the pod2usage output be the documentation from the calling file.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ONe of the many options to pod2usage is

"-input"
       A reference to a filehandle, or the pathname of a file from which
       the invoking script's pod documentation should be read.  It
       defaults to the file indicated by $0 ($PROGRAM_NAME for users of
       English.pm).